# how to send content using postfix?

Tags: command-line, server, email, postfix, mail

I need to be able to send the content of two files via email at the same time. I can now send it as two separate emails.

I was able to send the content of one file via one mail message like this:

```
mail -s "numeric data" eg@example.com < /home/num1.txt
```

How do I send the content of 2 files at the same time ?

If I use it like this:

```
mail -s "numeric data" eg@example.com < /home/num1.txt /home/num2.txt
```

It will send only the first content and edit the second file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con`cat`enate the files and feed to `mail` using a pipe:

```
cat /home/num1.txt /home/num2.txt | mail -s "numeric data" eg@example.com
```

Comment: worked great. thx !

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of different ways of combining the two files into one input stream but I'd personally rather have them **attached** as two separate files:

```
mail -s "numeric data" destination@example.com -A ~/num1.txt -A ~/num2.txt
```

Comment: `bsd-mailx` doesn't have `-A`

Comment: I use `mime-construct` to build an email with attachments.  It is especially nice when attaching plain text, as you can flag them as inline attachments so that they are both immediately viewable when reading the mail, but also can be detached and saved as separate files.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
mail -s "numeric data" destination@example.com < <(cat foo bar)
```

or with the name of the files in the mail

```
mail -s "numeric data" destination@example.com < <(awk 'FNR != NR || FNR == 1 {print FILENAME} {print}' foo bar)
```

---

*Example*

```
Date: Fri,  2 Oct 2015 15:01:20 +0200 (CEST)
From: your name <your.name@example.com>
To: destination@example.com
Subject: numeric data

foo
foobar

bar
barfoo
```

Answer (score -1):

You can give a try to multiple files input redirection as the following:

```
mail -s "numeric data" eg@example.com < /home/num1.txt < /home/num2.txt
```

Comment: In bash, and most shells, only the last redirection takes effect.